# PHP uploading JPG issues

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a small problem.
I have a website where users can upload images but som .JPG images get uploaded but are not visible.
The upload service accepts .jpg, .JPG, .jpeg ,.JPEG
The size of the file is also under the maxium size that i allow.

I can se that the specific image i uploaded by looking in the upload folder on the server with FileZilla.

All other images are shown without any problems.
Can the file that i try to upload may be damaged?
Is there a way of check if the file is damaged/corrupt?

```
    $file_name = $file['image']['name'];
    $tmp_file = $file['image']['tmp_name'];
    $extention = end(explode('.',$file_name));

    if($extention == "png" || $extention == "jpg" || $extention == "jpeg" || $extention == "JPG" || $extention == "JPEG" || $extention == "svg"){

        try{

            $file_destination = '../files/'.$file_name;
            //var_dump($file_destination);

            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_file,$file_destination)){

                echo    "
                        <div class='alert alert-success mainbox col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2'>
                           File uploaded successfully!
                        </div>
                       ";
            }else{
                echo    "
                        <div class='alert alert-danger mainbox col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2'>
                          Something went wrong;
                        </div>
                       ";
            }

        }catch(PDOException $ex){
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
```

Thanks in advace!

Comment: show you tried code

Comment: Do you really think that *we are experts and have a capability to predict things without looking at code*?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to upload my code! here you go!

Comment: I'm twitching at your case checks - it'd be better to cast them all to upper or lower case and check once.

You say that you can see the file uploaded by ftp. What happens if you download it by ftp and try to open it from your computer?

Comment: @gedq the file opens up without any problem hen i download it from the FTP client

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you experienced trouble with `chmod`.

Take a look on the file's permission after upload.

Comment: Th folder that contains the uploaded files is chmod 777 so it should not be a problem. The file has 644

Comment: @Webbie ... you are so very, very wrong, **777** is a problem but for totally different reasons: http://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver

Comment: Ok! Can you please be more specific?

Comment: @Webbie ... read the link and learn about \*nix permisions. You should *never* need to 777 anything on a web server; that, in effect, gives total read/write/execute permissions to everyone with access to the box - including guest FTP accounts.

Comment: Thank you! But the problem still remains.

Comment: I can see now that the problem occurs when i try to load a photo that is taken with a iphone. Is this i known problem?